How much of this table can be filled in?
This puzzle is my idea, but please note I do not have a 15/15 solution for it; I don't even know if it's possible to fill in all blanks. However I will accept the solution with the most non-blanks.
For each cell in the below table, can you find an English word with one unique letter and two letters that appear twice each, where the unique letter is in a position indicated by the row and the arrangement of the non-unique letters is indicated by the column? For example, in row 1 column 1 (Manna), the unique letter is in position 1 (indicated by Xxxxx) and the four non-unique letters are in the form xyyx.

Score is out of 15.
Trade names are allowed if they have an English Wikipedia page. Ex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volvo
Archaic and Loan words are allowed if they have an "English" section in their Wiktionary page. They are not allowed if they only have "Middle English" or "Old English". Ex: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/halal#English
You do not have to use the pre-filled words such as Volvo; you can substitute your own if you feel like it.
Don't just edit the Wiki!

4/15 solution below. (My personal best is 7/15)




xyyx
xxyy
xyxy




Aaaaa
Manna
_____
Halal


aAaaa
_____
aMass
_____


aaAaa
_____
_____
voLvo


aaaAa
_____
_____
_____


aaaaA
_____
_____
_____



Side note: My personal preference would be to avoid trade names and archaic/loan words, but in order to be completely impartial, it will not impact the scoring.

rot13(Lbh cebonoyl unir gurfr be rdhvinyragf, ohg:  GBBGF, ZVZVP, YYNZN, EBGBE)

Sbe GBBGF, ZVZVP naq EBGBE V unq gur rdhvinyragf NEENL, CNCNY naq YRIRY. V qvqa'g unir na rdhvinyrag sbe YYNZN.


 | |xyyx |xxyy |xyxy |
 |-----|-----|-----|-----|
 |Aaaaa|Gamma|Cooee|Ceded|
 |aAaaa|sElls|tUtee|eAses|
 |aaAaa|stAts|aaLii|onIon|
 |aaaAa|seePs|llaMa|mamBa|
 |aaaaA|erreD|_____|tutuS|


 All the words above were found without the use of wordlists (aside from aaLii, which was found by Daniel Mathias using YAWL). EEAAO is the closest word I could find for xxyyA, but it's an acronym and thus invalid.


Oof! Well done! I learned a couple of new words: Cooee and Tutee. Eevee feels to me like it should be an answer, however some people may disagree. It's not an acronym and it even has a Wikipedia page, on the other hand it is invented by a franchise. I don't think I would allow EEAAO. So it looks like the 15/15 is impossible, do you agree?

I didn't notice that eevee has 4 of the same letter... Not sure about that one.

I personally wouldn't accept Eevee since it feels too proper noun-y to me, but I could see others feeling differently. I couldn't find anything that fits the xxyyA pattern that most people would accept unfortunately, so it does look like the 15/15 is impossible based on that.

The xxyyA pattern has no solutions in YAWL. As for the other, aalii is the unique solution.

I don't know what Ceded is, I had Queue in mind

Not entirely serious answers, but… There's a song called "AAAAA", a film called "Mmmmm" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmmmm), a band/project called "oOoOO" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OOoOO), and an episode of the old "The Outer Limits" TV show entitled "ZZZZZ" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZZZZZ); those could fill in any blanks?  (Along with ever other cell in the table…)

@Chronocidal I know you aren't being serious, but I think you've just proved that for the puzzle to be meaningful, x, y and A have to be different letters.

@matt_rule Which then also confirms "Eevee" as invalid too xD
